# Language Translation Issue with Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.0, language-translation

I have developed a simple language translating module with cakePHP 2.0 using a below tutorial:

http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/11/28/cakephp-url-based-language-switching-for-i18n-and-l10n-internationalization-and-localization/

Its working fine
If i run below URL
http://[SITe_URL]/posts/index

Language translating Links are getting converted to 
http://[SITe_URL]/eng/posts/index
http://[SITe_URL]/fre/posts/index

But If i Pass a below URl
http://[SITe_URL]/posts/edit/3

anguage translating Links are getting converted to 
http://[SITe_URL]/eng/posts/edit
http://[SITe_URL]/fre/posts/edit

instead of

http://[SITe_URL]/fre/posts/edit/3

I think there is and issue with Rounting princliple i have passed in route.php

Please send me your suggestions to help me out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I tried a simple solution for the above problem by adding the extra parameter in the link generation while switching the language.

```
<?php 
    $param = null;
    if(isset($this->params['pass'][0]))
        $param = $this->params['pass'][0];
    echo $this->Html->link('English', array($param,'language'=>'eng'));
    echo ' | ';
    echo $this->Html->link('French', array($param,'language'=>'fre')); 
?>
```